# Google Data Studio: Formula difference between first and last values within date range?

Tags: looker-studio

In Google Data Studio, I need to show the difference between the first value and the last value, in a selected date range (selected by a filter in the report).

Example data set:

```
    date       | total_eggs
    -----------------------
    2018-01-11 | 7
    2018-01-12 | 7
    2018-01-13 | 7
    2018-01-14 | 8
    2018-01-15 | 9
    2018-01-16 | 10
```

So, I need a formula/calculated field that will show that the difference between first and latest value 'total_eggs' = 3. This means, we have gained 3 eggs over time.

This should be simple, but not finding the answer to this in relation to Google Data Studio specific implementation.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find any way to do that in a table as a running difference. You could do it as a scorecard with a field as simple as

```
max(total_eggs)-min(total_eggs)
```

That would change if you change the dates.